# asp.net logout link changed after session timed out

Tags: asp.net, authentication, status

i used the loginstatus control of the asp.net,
after the session timeout, of an application,
the logout link changed to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an expected behavior if your session timeout and forms cookie timeout is set to same value.You should change the timeout in the 'forms' section to change this...

`<forms
   name="name" 
   loginUrl="URL" 
   defaultUrl="URL"
   timeout="[MM]"
   path="path"
   requireSSL="[true|false]"
   slidingExpiration="[true|false]">
   enableCrossAppRedirects="[true|false]"
   cookieless="[UseUri|UseCookies|AutoDetect|UseDeviceProfile]" 
   domain="domain name"
   ticketCompatibilityMode="[Framework20|Framework40]">
</forms>`